# Somebody explain me the render in flask

Tags: python, flask

i am new in Flask. 
I understand the next code, which i think passes the article variable to the template articles.html

```
    @app.route('/articles')
    def articles():
    return render_template("articles.html", articles=Articles)
```

But the follwing one is which i do not understand:

```
@app.route('/articles/<string:id>/')
def article(id):
    return render_template("article.html", id=id)
```

Can somebody explain me? The meaning of `"<string:id>"` and the parameter `id` in the funcion article and also the `id`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the [Flask Quickstart](http://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#routing) yet? It explains how routing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flask `/articles/<string:id>/` specifies a path parameter, so that when a request is made to e.g.

```
/articles/123/
```

the variable `id` is given the value `123` -- as a string since this is the specified type.

So for any given article name, this is passed on to the the rendering for use with `article.html`.

Comment: And what about the parameter? def article(id)

Comment: It is what allows the value to pass from the routing (`@app.route`) to the rendering (`render_template`). Please set up a small example on your own machine to experiment with this feature. You will learn a thousand times more by doing than by just asking questions. :)